# Jetpack compose - Immediately navigate to new screen with loader and later render whole page

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using BottomNavigation along with NavHost to navigate between multiple screens for my Android app. When I switch from one screen to other using bottom navigation items, everything is loaded first in new screen and then transition happens from old screen to new screen.

I'm looking for ways to immediately navigate to new screen with a circular-loader, and then render the whole page when data is available from backend API. I am sure there must be ways to do this. It's just that I'm not able to figure it out.

Here is how my navigation-controller looks like:

```
package com.app.example

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.BottomNavigation
import androidx.compose.material.BottomNavigationItem
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController


@Composable
fun NavigationController(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    context: Context
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = NavigationItem.Home.route,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 56.dp)
    ) {

        composable(NavigationItem.Home.route) {
            RenderSummaryScreen(context)
        }

        composable(NavigationItem.Transactions.route) {
            RenderTransactionsScreen(context)
        }

        composable(NavigationItem.Profile.route) {
            RenderProfileScreen(context)
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun Navigation(context: Context) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    val items = listOf(
        NavigationItem.Home,
        NavigationItem.Transactions,
        NavigationItem.Profile,
    )

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {

                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

                items.forEach { item ->
                    val isSelected = currentRoute == item.route
                    val labelColor: Color
                    val icon: ImageVector
                    val fontWeight: FontWeight

                    if (isSelected) {
                        labelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        icon = item.selectedIcon
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                    } else {
                        labelColor = Color.DarkGray
                        icon = item.unselectedIcon
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light
                    }

                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        selected = isSelected,
                        label = {
                            Text(text = item.label, fontWeight = fontWeight)
                        },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = icon,
                                contentDescription = "Selected tab",
                                tint = labelColor
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            if (!isSelected) {
                                navController.navigate(item.route) {
                                    popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
                                        inclusive = true
                                    }
                                    launchSingleTop = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        NavigationController(
            navHostController = navController,
            context = context
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `navigate` immediately transitions to the new screen without any delay.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm making couple of API calls in the new screen, and since there is some lag between clicking the button and navigating to new screen, I'm assuming that transition happens only when new screen is ready with complete data.

I might be wrong though. I've just started learning Android development, so not really sure about anything.

Comment: You should use the state for the screen. so when the screen opens up the first time the Screen state is loading, it will show a loading indicator and then you try to load data in LaunchedEffect(). it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this with just using if-else condition in your `RenderSummaryScreen/RenderTransactionsScreen/RenderProfileScreen`:

in any of your screen functions:

```
if (isLoading) CircularProgressIndicator()
else {
    ScreenContent()
}
```

Comment: Where does "isLoading" come from?

Comment: From viewModel. Initial value is true, and when the data is loaded set isLoading to false